# Newbie help Adding function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery menu that is represented with these paramaters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){


                jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
                        { 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/winamp.png",
                            alt  : "Winamp",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}
                        },  { 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/vlc.png",
                            alt  : "VLC Media Player",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}  
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/QuickTime.png",
                            alt  : "Quick Time Player",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.qtl';return false}
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/WMP.png",
                            alt  : "Windows Media Player",
                            fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.asx';return false}
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/popup.png",
                            alt  : "נגן Popup",
                            fn   : function(){$("#popupplay").click();return false}
                        },{ 
                            path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/iTunes.png",
                            alt  : "iTunes",
                            fn   : function(){alert('...בקרוב');return false}
                        }],
                    beforeMenuOpen: function(){
                        jQuery('<div id="shadow"></div>').css(
                        {
                            'position':'fixed',
                            'background-color':'#000000',
                            'opacity': 0.6,
                            'width':'100%',
                            'height':'100%',
                            'z-index' :999,
                            'top':0,
                            'left':0
                        }).appendTo('body');
                    },
                    beforeMenuClose: function(){
                        jQuery('#shadow').remove();
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

That menu is operated with right click. i need to change that to hover.

The author of the plugin gave a snippet of what to insert:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//init my jPie
   var jPieMenu = $(#myelement').pieMenu({icon : [ { 
                               path : "path/to/images.png",
                               alt  : "icon",
                               fn   : function(){alert('Click:: icon');return false;}
                          }] });
   $('#myelement').hover(function(){
      if($('#'+jPieMenu.id).css('display') != 'block') //if jpie is not visible
          jPieMenu.initMenu(200,200);
   })
})
```

Only problem is i dont know where to insert and what..i always get unexpected token. 
Can someone look at my code above and suggest a place to insert it?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: believe it or not I actually just stumbled onto this question and quickly realized it was yours, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set the pie menu to a variable, so that you can reference its id:

Change:

```
jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
```

to

```
var pieMenu = jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
```

Now we have a way of referencing both the menu itself and the containing element, #promo, which I assume is just a div which when is hovered over needs to set off the menu.

Anyway, add this:

```
$('#promo').hover(function(){
      if($('#'+pieMenu.id).css('display') != 'block') //if jpie is not visible
          pieMenu.initMenu(200,200);
   })
```

between the last two sets of `})`'s and you should be good to go.

Edit: and yeah, the author that gave you that code missed a quote. Shouldn't matter, though, since you already have that part coded.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help...Phillip's var add-on did the trick..:)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the `$('#myelement').pieMenu` declaration with your existing code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//init my jPie
   var jPieMenu = $('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [ {   // replace these lines with your existing code
                               path : "path/to/images.png",
                               alt  : "icon",
                               fn   : function(){alert('Click:: icon');return false;}
                          }] });
   $('#promo').hover(function(){ // This ID needs to be the same as your element
      if($('#'+jPieMenu.id).css('display') != 'block') //if jpie is not visible
          jPieMenu.initMenu(200,200);
   })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, in your second block of code in the third line, there is a missing quote at the beginning of #myelement, which is causing everything else in that line to act as a string

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){


            jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
                    { 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/winamp.png",
                        alt  : "Winamp",
                        fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}
                    },  { 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/vlc.png",
                        alt  : "VLC Media Player",
                        fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.pls';return false}  
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/QuickTime.png",
                        alt  : "Quick Time Player",
                        fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.qtl';return false}
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/WMP.png",
                        alt  : "Windows Media Player",
                        fn   : function(){('Click:: Plus');window.location.href = 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/tunein/tranceilfm.asx';return false}
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/popup.png",
                        alt  : "נגן Popup",
                        fn   : function(){$("#popupplay").click();return false}
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/iTunes.png",
                        alt  : "iTunes",
                        fn   : function(){alert('...בקרוב');return false}
                    }],
                beforeMenuOpen: function(){
                    jQuery('<div id="shadow"></div>').css(
                    {
                        'position':'fixed',
                        'background-color':'#000000',
                        'opacity': 0.6,
                        'width':'100%',
                        'height':'100%',
                        'z-index' :999,
                        'top':0,
                        'left':0
                    }).appendTo('body');
                },
                beforeMenuClose: function(){
                    jQuery('#shadow').remove();
                }
            });
            jQuery('#promo').hover(function(){ // This ID needs to be the same as your element
                if(!jQuery('#'+jPieMenu.id).is(":visible")) //if jpie is not visible
                    jPieMenu.initMenu(200,200);
            })
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Variable `jPieMenu` doesn't exist. You forgot `var jPieMenu = $('#promo')...`